# Outlook, Show subfolders as items inside a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to somehow have the folder pane minimised with only favorites showing and in the favorites have 1 folder that when you open you see all the subfolders inside if instead of emails received.

For example [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LadzU.png) as you can see in the screenshot i have the folder pane minimized and when i click on folder "Organized" i want to be able to see all the subfolders and be able to click on that subfolder to see all the emails in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with LPchip, and I have tested on my Outlook, it works for me like below.
[image]

If that could meet your need, here are my specific steps of creating the search folder:

- Right-click the search folder>New Search Folder>Create a custom
  Search Folder
- Type the Name> Browser>choose the folder that you need to add

[image]

- Right-click to add the search folder to favorite.

Hope that would be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a search folder to search for all email in your entire mailbox, or even limit it to a specific subset of maps. This folder can be added to your favorites without showing the rest.

Inside the searchfolder, you can group on folder to keep all emails separated in the list ordered by folder alphabetically. This allows you to create a view with your inbox, sent items and say a folder called "organized" all in the same view.

If you collapse all the groups you can open one group to see those emails, but you probably will like what this offers more, so you break away from the folder structure entirely (such as sorting by date and simply view all email regardless their folder sorted by date with a small column telling you in what folder it is).